# MySQL query take more time to execution

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, left-join

```
SELECT 
  gst_journal.*,
  salesmain.TransactionNo 
FROM
  `gst_journal` 
  LEFT JOIN salesmain 
    ON (
      gst_journal.docNo = salesmain.InvoiceNo 
      AND gst_journal.Source = salesmain.Source
    ) 
WHERE (
    MONTH(salesmain.TDate) = '10' 
    AND YEAR(salesmain.TDate) = '2013' 
    AND salesmain.TDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d') 
    AND STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-31', '%Y-%m-%d') 
    AND (
      (
        gst_journal.inOutTax = 'OUT' 
        AND gst_journal.taxType IN ('SR', 'GST') 
        AND gst_journal.Source IN ('AR', 'NR', 'BR', 'PR', 'JV', 'CR')
      )
    )
  ) 
  OR (
    MONTH(gst_journal.TDate) = '10' 
    AND YEAR(gst_journal.TDate) = '2013' 
    AND (
      gst_journal.TDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND STR_TO_DATE('2013-10-31', '%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND (
        gst_journal.taxType = 'SR' 
        AND gst_journal.Source IN ('BR')
      )
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY gst_journal.Tdate,
  salesmain.TDate ;
```

this query run properly and records give correct but it take to time run.
Any one help to optimize time query.

Thanks

Comment: When you ask for an optimization advice at least provide exact table schema(s) `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`, indices created on them `SHOW INDEXES FROM <table_name>`, result of `EXPLAIN <your_query>` all in textual form. How much time does it take to execute this query? What is your expected execution time?

Comment: it take 260 second which is take more than 60 second.

Comment: result of EXPLAIN         
`1  SIMPLE  gst_journal  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 7795  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort


1  SIMPLE  salesmain  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 8036  Using where`

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: yes peter i need help for this query optimization..